# Special Characters in HTML Element

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

What I'm trying to do is output a percent sign (%) directly into a < td > tag. Below is my code:

```
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="item_container" %%=v(@Item_Container_Style)=%%>
  ...
```

When I test the XSL I get the following error:

```
  SAXParseException: Expected an attribute name (Set_A_Custom.xsl, line 205, column 38)
```

So basically it's seeing "%%=v(@Item_Container_Style)=%%" as invalid HTML but I need this code to be there.

If you are wondering why I am doing this it is because I am writing the XSL to output HTML that contains AMPscript (An ExactTarget proprietary Scripting language). You don't need to know anything about AMPscript though to help me out though, I just need to output the percent sign (%) in the HTML and everything will work.

Any ideas? For the record I'm using XSL 1.0. Thanks all!

Comment: The input you have provided is not a well-formed XML so it can not be parsed. Before loading your stylesheet, you must process your so-called AMPscript. Another possibility would be to call your stylesheet with parameters.

Comment: I haven't included any XML as I didn't see it initially relevant. I also can't process AMPscript ahead of time as the code I'm creating is being passed for dynamic rendering. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XSLT stylesheet must itself be well-formed XML, so you can't include this kind of construct directly in the stylesheet.  If the XSLT processor you're using supports `disable-output-escaping` then you would be able to do something like

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<td class="item_container" %%=v(@Item_Container_Style)=%%>]]></xsl:text>
      ...
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</td>]]></xsl:text>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If it does not allow `disable-output-escaping` then your only option is to use the `text` output method, and write *all* the tags you want to output as text with the angle brackets escaped (or in CDATA).

Comment: This ended up working great. It was very simple and works for the use case provided. Thank you for your input, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DigitalMC Be sure to consider Michael Kay's post, he has a very valid point there.

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm trying to do is output a percent sign (%) directly into a `<td>` tag.

Not possible with the "html" or "xml" output modes. XSLT has been designed to create *syntactically sane* HTML, you cannot make it do anything else.

Of course you could switch to the "text" output mode and do whatever you like, but generating HTML this way it a lot harder.

Alternatively you can use `disable-output-escaping`, if your XSLT processor supports it, but this will quickly degenerate your XSLT stylesheet into a mess if you need to do it in many places.

---

That being said, here's a proposal. In XSLT you use the "html" output mode and this:

```
<td 
  class="item_container" 
  amp-1="%%=v({@Item_Container_Style})%%" 
  amp-2="%%=v({@Some_Other_Element})%%"
>
    some text %%=v(<xsl:value-of select="Other_Stuff" />)%% more text
</td>
```

That is syntactically valid XSLT which covers both cases (multiple placeholders in attributes, multiple placeholders in the text) and creates syntactically valid HTML:

```
<td 
  class="item_container" 
  amp-1="%%=v(item container style content)%%" 
  amp-2="%%=v(some other element content)%%"
>
    Here some text %%=v(other stuff)%%
</td>
```

and then you use a post-processing step to convert that HTML into AMPscript:

Regex-replace `\bamp-\d+="(%%[\s\S]*?%%)"` with `$1`, which would result in

```
<td 
  class="item_container" 
  %%=v(item container style content)%% 
  %%=v(some other element content)%%
>
    Here some text %%=v(other stuff)%%
</td>
```

Handling HTML with regular expressions is generally strongly dis-recommended, but this might just be a narrow-enough use case.

Comment: This is a really creative solution. I don't think there is any space for a post-processor in this process. I'm going to fiddle with this though as I like where your head is at.

Comment: Well, how do you apply the XSLT to your input XML? There *must* be some plumbing that you can extend.

Comment: We technically it is possible. But we are delivering this as a one-off custom solution to extend a current technical offering. So we would have to change our code base to add an additional post-processor. Anything I could include in the XSL would work, anything outside would be out of scope I think.

Comment: I see. Well, it looks like banging on it with `disable-output-escaping` is, although inelegant, your best option.

Comment: Yeah but I really liked your solution. Thanks so much for taking the time to detail it Tomalak.

Answer (score 2):

AMPScript appears to have a standards-based syntax as an alternative to its proprietary syntax:

Delimiter Comparison

The table below demonstrates the similarities between standard AMPscript delimiters and server-side delimiters.

```
Standard AMPscript Delimiter    Tag-based AMPscript Delimiter
%%[                             <script runat=server language=ampscript>
etc
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks Michael! I was aware of the example you provided, but not sure how adding < script > tags would be any easier. I could begin wrapping everything in SSJS variables but  at that point it might just be as easy to go the < xsl:text > route. If you had another idea I'm missing let me know for sure!

Comment: The tag-based syntax covers script _blocks_ but not the inline `%%= ... =%%` constructs used in the question.